# Android ListView issues. Will not show views added

Tags: android, listview

When I run this code in debug, I can see that my `TextView`s and seekbars are being added into the array and attached to the adaptor, but they still are not showing on my screen. Ideas?
Thanks

`ColorsActivity`

```
public class ColorsActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
SeekBarAdaptor seekBarAdaptor;

//List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
ArrayList<LinearLayout> seekBarArrayList=null;
// TextView myValueText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.seekbars);

    setContentView(R.layout.seekbarlist);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout red = (LinearLayout)inflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.seekbars, null);
     CustomSeekBar.createCustomSeekBar(this, red, "red");

    //CustomSeekBar blue = new CustomSeekBar(this, "blue");
    //CustomSeekBar green = new CustomSeekBar(this, "green");

    //Initialize ListView        
    ListView lstTest= getListView();


     //Initialize our ArrayList
    seekBarArrayList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    seekBarArrayList.add(red);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(blue);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(green);

    //Initialize our array adapter 
    seekBarAdaptor = new SeekBarAdaptor(this, R.layout.seekbars, seekBarArrayList);

    //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
    lstTest.setAdapter(seekBarAdaptor);
   // lstTest.addView(red);



   // Amarino.connect(this, "00:11:11:21:05:53");
}



}
```

CustomSeekBar

```
 public class CustomSeekBar //implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
{
static Context myContext;
static TextView myValue;
static TextView myLabel;
static SeekBar mySeekBar;

public static void  createCustomSeekBar(Context context, LinearLayout layout, String label){
    myContext = context;        
    mySeekBar = new SeekBar(myContext);
    myLabel = new TextView(myContext);
    myValue = new TextView(myContext);

    myLabel.setText(label);
    //mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    layout.addView(myLabel);
    layout.addView(myValue);
    layout.addView(mySeekBar);


}

 /*public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch)                                    {
    myValue.setText(progress);      
    //Amarino.sendDataToArduino(myContext, "00:11:11:21:05:53", 'A', progress);
 }
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

 }
 public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
 }*/


}
```

seekbars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
>

</LinearLayout>
```

seekbarslist

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

seekbaradaptor

```
public class SeekBarAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>
{

int resource;
String response;
Context context;

LinearLayout alertView;    
TextView seekBarLabel; 
TextView seekBarValue; 


//Initialize adapter
public SeekBarAdaptor(Context context, int resource, List<LinearLayout> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource;

}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout alertView;
    //Get the current alert object
    LinearLayout sb = getItem(position);


    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        alertView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, alertView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        alertView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    //seekBarLabel = (TextView)alertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBarLabel);

    //seekBarLabel.setText(Integer.toString(position));

    return alertView;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() if you're modifying the array after it's added to the adapter.

Found your bug in SeekBarAdaptor.  It's in getView and I commented/fixed it.

```
public class SeekBarAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>
{

int resource;
String response;
Context context;

LinearLayout alertView;    
TextView seekBarLabel; 
TextView seekBarValue; 


//Initialize adapter
public SeekBarAdaptor(Context context, int resource, List<LinearLayout> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource;

}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout alertView;
    //Get the current alert object

    // I don't know what you're doing here but you're never using it.
    LinearLayout sb = getItem(position);


    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);

        // here's your bug!  you forgot to assign this to alertView.
        alertView = vi.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }
    else
    { 
        alertView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    //seekBarLabel = (TextView)alertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBarLabel);

    //seekBarLabel.setText(Integer.toString(position));

    return alertView;
}


}
```

Comment: I will try this when I get home. To be honest, the adaptor I grabbed from someone else. I should have taken more time to look at it. Thanks for your help. Ill let you know how it works.

Comment: I am now receiving this in logcat

`04-04 21:38:20.183: E/AndroidRuntime(16032): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView`

Looking at 

[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

It says that it expects a single TextView, but that you can override this. 
Im pulling my hair out over here. Been trying to get this going for a couple weeks now.

Comment: Oops!  I think you need to change my "true" to a "false" in the `vi.inflate` line.  Give that a shot.  I edited my answer above to take it into account.  That boolean specifies whether or not to add the inflated view as a child of the other view you passed in (and `parent` is a `ListView` which means this isn't supported).

Comment: Still no change. Going through debug, objects are added to listview. I can navigate through listview to the adapter to the array which contains my linearlayout which holds my 2 textviews and a seekbar..
But they do not appear on the screen. I looked more into setAdapter()
It looks like it requires a ListAdapter, not sure if that makes a difference, but I tried type casting to array adapter and I am still having the same trouble.

Comment: Why are you taking a list of `LinearLayout`s as an argument into your adapter?  In a typical use case, one would pass in an array of data objects containing the set of data to be displayed in your `ListView`, and then in `getView` use that data (which you can get by `getItem(position)`) to populate the view that you are returning from `getView`.

Comment: Because CustomSeekBar is creating a seekbar and 2 text views within a linearlayout. So the adapter would need to hold many of these CustomSeekBars.

Comment: Notice  `seekBarArrayList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>()` this is passed into the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize ListView        
ListView lstTest= getListView();
```

replace the above line with below

```
ListView lstTest = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.mylist);
```

and in `seekbarslist.xml` change

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/mylist"
```

and try now this one also change

```
public class ColorsActivity extends ListActivity
```

to

```
public class ColorsActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: I am currently at work and will look into this once I get home, but I do not see why this would change anything. You are still grabbing the listview...

Comment: FYI If you change it to mylist, it has to be @+id/mylist..

And you have to have a 'list' when you extend ListActivity

Comment: I did try to change it to mylist. It forced closed because YOU MUST HAVE A LISTVIEW NAMED LIST.

Comment: Taken from Android development site .....

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"

Comment: I tried exactly what you said to do and I receive a force close.

Comment: First error in log
04-03 21:43:11.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{thisPackage.Tabs/thisPackage.Tabs.ColorsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Since you edited above to extend activity instead of listactivity, it is no longer force closing. But I am still in the same position. The textviews and seekbar do not show up in the listview.

Comment: ???????? Are you ok????
The textviews and seekbar do not show up in the listview.